# Dotted underlines in Word for Macbook users 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office

I am doing an editorial job and need to underline some words with red dotted underlines. How do you do this using Word for Mac users? The version I have is 2011, on a MacBook with Snow Leopard software.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text you want to underline, right click and select 'font'.

Now you can set the underline style and color.

[image]